# Object Oriented Programming - Inheritance C++, Code does not compile

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance

## Source Code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A
{
    private:
        long int a;
    public:
        long int b,x;
        
        void set_a(){
            cout<<"Enter variable A's value (integer) \nAnswer: ";
            cin>>a;
            x=a;
        }
        
        void display_a(){
            cout<<"\n value for Variable A: "<<x<<endl;
        }
        
        void getdata(){
            cout<<"Enter variable B's value (integer) \nAnswer: ";
            cin>>b;
        }
};


class B:public A
{
    private:
      long int prod;
    public:
    
    void prod(){
        prod = x*b;
        }
        
    void display(){
        cout<<"Displaying product of variables A and B \nProduct: "<<prod<<endl;    
        }
};



int main()
{
    A obj;
    B obj2;
    
    obj.set_a();
    obj.display_a();
    obj2.display();
}
```

### Complier Error Message

```
  37  |         }
      |         ^
main.cpp:31:16: note: previous declaration ‘long int B::prod’
   31 |       long int prod;
      |                ^~~~
```

---

I have just started learning Inheritance functions from Object Oriented programming so I am quite the novice. I believe the program lies within the Inheritance function sub class but I am not too sure.

Also, I am pretty sure there is a method to checking the solution to error messages from the compiler but I don't know what it is or where to look, so some assistance would be helpful

Comment: Please post the entire compiler error message, or at least the first 3 error messages. It seems that you did not post the first error message, which is usually the most important one.

Comment: You cannot have a method `prod` with the exact same name as a data member. Also - better to avoid `using namespace std` - see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 problems with your code described below.

##### Problem 1

You have a method `prod` with the same name as the data member `prod` in class `B`.

To solve this change, you can either change the name of the method or the data member so that they're not the same as shown below.

##### Problem 2

The code has **undefined behavior** because you're using the value of the uninitialized data member `b`.

To **solve** this make sure that `b` is initialized(or assigned) before using its value as shown below. Similarly, `prod` is uninitialized.

Additionally, you were creating a separate object `obj` and calling the member functions on that object. That `obj` is different from the subobject `A` inside `B` object `obj2`. This has been fixed and highlighted using comments in the below program so that you can see what changes have been made.

```
class A
{
    private:
        long int a;
    public:
        long int b,x;
        
        void set_a(){
            std::cout<<"Enter variable A's value (integer) \nAnswer: ";
            std::cin>>a;
            x=a;
           
        }
        
        void display_a(){
            std::cout<<"\n value for Variable A: "<<x<<std::endl;
        }
        
        void getdata(){
            std::cout<<"Enter variable B's value (integer) \nAnswer: ";
            std::cin>>b;
        }
};


class B:public A
{
    private:
      long int prod;
    public:
//-------vvvvvvv------------->name changed to product so that it is different from prod data member
    void product(){
        //call these methods here inside product instead of calling them outside on a separater `A` object
        set_a(); 
        getdata();
        display_a();
       
        prod = x*b;
        }
        
    void display(){
        std::cout<<"Displaying product of variables A and B \nProduct: "<<prod<<std::endl;    
        }
};



int main()
{
   //no need to create a separate `A` object
   
    B obj2;
    obj2.product();
    obj2.display();
}
```

[Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/VE1Jq0ZJt)

In the above program the call to member functions `set_a`, `getdata` and `dispaly_a` is made from inside the member function `product` instead of calling them on a separate `A` object.